# Where to find the Vatican copyright law?

Tags: copyright, reference-request, vatican-city-state

This [article](http://www.globallegalpost.com/global-view/copyright-and-the-vatican-41065795/) writes about the current copyright law in the Vatican City State. It claims there is a new law from March 19, 2011, no. CXXXII.

Where can I find this law? According to this Vatican [website](http://www.vaticanstate.va/content/vaticanstate/en/stato-e-governo/organi-dello-stato/organi-del-potere-giudiziario.html) the Vatican laws are published "in a special supplement of the Acta Apostolicae Sedis". The normal AAS can be found [here](http://www.vatican.va/archive/aas/index_en.htm), but this does not include the special supplement.

Does anyone know a (online) resource where this supplement or the text of the copyright law can be found?

The Pontifical University Gregroiana has the supplement in its [library](https://oseegenius.unigre.it/pug/resource?uri=45111&v=l). If there is no online resource, does someone know if it is normal for theological faculties outside of Rome to have this supplement in its library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://www.wipo.int/edocs/lexdocs/laws/it/va/va003it.pdf) is the law. I cannot find an official Vatican website with this document, but WIPO would not lie.